# flash of un-styled content. How to hide all custom fonts before the page has loaded?

Tags: jquery, fouc

I'm trying to fight FOUC. My site relies heavily on custom fonts. I've already made it not display the page until the fonts have loaded, but in opera I still get a bit of FOUC on each page change.

So, I thought I'd apply additional measures and hide ALL text that uses the custom font. Is there an easy way to select all divs, spans that have `font-family: CustomFont;` in the css file and make them not display text before the font has loaded?

EDIT: Or just delay 0.5 seconds?